# Change game from portrait to landscape dynamically

Tags: java, android, orientation, libgdx

I have multiple classes that implement `Screen`.

I want to, say, have the **Main Menu** screen `portrait`, then the **Play Screen** `landscape`. Is there anyway of changing the `orientation` dynamically?

I thought I could just start another `Activity` and have the **Play Screen** extend `Game`. And the new `Activity` would `intialize` the **Play Screen**. But it appears that you can't call `startActivity` or the like, obviously, as `LibGDX` is platform independent.

I use `Gdx.graphics.getWidth()` and `Gdx.graphics.getHeight()` to align `Sprites` and `Actors`, so it looks "right" on different devices.

I've also tried swapping the `Gdx.graphics.getWidth()` and `Gdx.graphics.getHeight()`, respectively, but can't seem to get the position of sprites and actors correct.

Also, in my manifest I have `orientation="landscape"`.

Here are some images that should make more sense.

So this is my **Main Menu** in `landscape`:
[image]

And this is my **Main Menu** in `portrait`:

[image]

The position and size of `Actors` and `Sprites` are all based on `Gdx.graphics.getWidth()` and `Gdx.graphics.getHeight()`. The only thing that changes between the two images is `orientation="landscape"` and `orientation="portrait"` in my manifest.

Now I want my **Main Menu** in `portrait` but the **Play Screen**, where the game is on, should be in `landscape`.

I initially started working on the **Play Screen** and the sizes and positions where set based on `orientation="landscape"`, and now that I am working on the **Main Menu** it is based on `orientation="portrait"`. Hence why I want to change the orientation dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have multiple `Activities`. To learn how to switch the orientation programmatically you can have a look at [this link](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/08/set-screen-orientation-programmatically.html).

As you said, LibGDX is platform-independent. That's why you cannot access your Android-`Activity` from your "core" code. To learn how to workaround that, have a look at [Interfacing with platform specific code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code).

When you call your interface to change the orientation from your game when doing a `Screen` transition, LibGDX will automatically call `resize(width, height)` with the new values and you can align your `Stage` and so on according to the new values.

Comment: Well, I use `Gdx.graphics.getWidth()` and `Gdx.graphics.getHeight()` so that gives me the correct width and height according to orientation.

Comment: Maybe I didn't completely understand your actual problem you are facing. Could you edit your question and tell what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: In that case my answer is still valid I think. The first link shows how you can switch the orientation when going from your main menu to your game screen. The second shows how to do it with LibGDX.

Comment: Yeah, I had a look at the links, I can't seem to get my head round the  **interfacing with platform specific code**. However, I knew how to change the `orientation` dynamically in Android. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm happy you got it to work. Interfacing is a bit tricky.

Answer (score 3):

This is a good question :) I develop noone's answer (which is correct)

How to set lanscape screen with Android sdk specific classes ?

And how to import android classes in a libgdx project ?

First of all note that Android classes can only be imported in the android project and not in the core. So there we save the Activity in a platform dependant object. Here is my AndroidLauncher:

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame;
import com.mygdx.game.util.Platform;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        PlatformAndroid platform = new PlatformAndroid();
        platform.setActivity(this);
        initialize(new MyGdxGame((Platform) platform ), cfg);
}

}
```

PlatformAndroid implements Platform. These two classes are made to access platform specific objects. Let's look at them :

```
public interface Platform {
   public void SetOrientation(String string);
}
```

and

```
package com.mygdx.game.android;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.mygdx.game.util.Platform;

public class PlatformAndroid extends AndroidApplication implements Platform {
    private Activity activity;
    @Override
    public void SetOrientation(String string) {
       if (string == "landscape"){
       activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
       }
    }
    public void setActivity(Activity activity){ this.activity = activity;   }
}
```

You can also create a PLatformDesktop called by the desktop launcher. Anyway, keep the platform variable in your classes and when you want to set the screen to landscape just call:

```
 platform.SetOrientation("landscape");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this solved it:

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stage.getViewport().setScreenSize(width, height);
}
```

For some reason, even though the screen resolution changed, the stage didn't know that. So I've told it to the stage.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a interface in core project and and declare a method with any name than implement that interface in your AndroidLauncher class. Give definition  of your method.

For me **GameOrien.java** is interface having method declaration

```
public interface GameOrien {

    public static final int PORTRAIT=1;

    public static final int LANDSCAPE=2;

    void setOrientation(int orientation);
}
```

In **AndroidLauncher.java** class which is in Android project.

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements GameOrien {

**...**

    @Override
    public void setOrientation(int orientation) {

        if(orientation==PORTRAIT)
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        else if(orientation==LANDSCAPE)
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }

}
```

When you want to change orientation for GamePlay just call setOrientaion() method of interface. Your orientation changed.