# How do I call a method in LibGDX in the "AndroidLauncher" class?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Is there a possibility in LibGDX to call methods in the "AndroidLauncher" class, have tried quite a lot but it does not go.
I hope someone can give me an answer.

Bye

Comment: The question is way too vauge to be answered. Try to give us more information like: what do you want to do? What did you tried (can share code)? What does not work? Do you have an error? Wrong/unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you're trying to call method of AndroidLauncher class which is in android module.

You can do this by interfacing, try this

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code

Comment: Hello Abhishek Aryan,

Thank you first for the quick reply.
I found a link here on Stackoverflow, where you have basically answered the same question before [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22130470/change-game-from-portrait-to-landscape-dynamically). However, when I call the interface method. The method is not called in the "AndroidLauncher" class. I can post something of my code: